# Approach to display dashboards on mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, layout, widget, dashboard

My team and I are currently working on an app (both iOS & Android) which uses a lot of the functionality of one the web apps we implemented. The web application (ASP.NET) basically renders and creates dashboards (of custom dimensions, specified by the end user). The dashboards use different libraries for the widgets (FusionCharts, GoogleCharts, standard .NET controls...)

Anyway, part of the functionality of the mobile app is to display the dashboards specific to each user. The question is: what is the best way to approach this requirements?
We've brainstormed here and came up with a couple:

1. One is to generate a screenshot of the dashboard on the .NET application and display that screenshot on the mobile app. However, this approach is very basic and does not provide any interactivity.
2. Another consists of recreating each dashboard on the mobile apps. The problem with this is that it involves recreating everything from scratch and issues related to inconsistencies   between the 2 versions of dashboard (mobile version vs web version) will arise.
3. Loading the dashboard on the mobile app using the URL of the dashboard.

Personally, I think the 3rd approach is the most suitable, since there not much coding needed, we just load the existing dashboard using their respective URLS.

The question is, how do we handle dashboard that are too wide..(height is not a problem since the user experience of scrolling up and down is not bad, but having to scroll left and right is not a good experience imo).. As far as I know, the width on iPhones is 320px (right?) so how do we handle a situation where we have a dashboard that is 1000px wide?

Is this a good approach for this requirement? Any other possible approaches?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like CSS Media Queries could be what you're after.  Take a look at [this example](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries).